# How can I filter "dpkg --get-selections" to just packages available in repositories?

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I would like to get a list of packages installed on one system and install all of them on another system.

I know that `dpkg --get-selections` can give me a list of all installed packages which I can pipe into `dpkg --set-selections` on the target system. However, some of the installed packages are ones that I built myself locally (using e.g. checkinstall) and are not available from the repositories. The `dpkg --set-selections` process will fail when it is unable to find these packages in the repositories.

So is there a way I can filter the list generated by `dpkg --get-selections` so that it only contains packages whose *currently-installed version* is available in my current repositories?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe Software Center has a feature for syncing between computers these days. If that handle missing packages correctly, it could solve your problem.

The issue here is that `dpkg` isn't aware of repositories, only installed packages. You can find out if a package is available in a repository by running `apt-cache policy $package`. If you see a repository in the `Version Table`, it's available there.

So, how about this?. It's slow, but should work:

```
dpkg --get-selections '*' \
  | while read line; do
    apt-cache policy $(echo "$line" | cut -f1 ) \
      | grep -q 'http://' \
      && echo "$line"
done
```

Comment: This will show the progress and write into a file: `total=$(dpkg --get-selections '*'|wc -l); i=0; dpkg --get-selections '*'   | while read line; do i=$(($i+1));    apt-cache policy $(echo "$line" | cut -f1 )       | grep -q 'http://'       && echo "$i/$total $line"; echo $line>>/var/tmp/dpkg-selection.list; done`

Answer (score -4):

Use the following command

```
dpkg --get-selections > installed-software
```

it will create a file called installed-software in your home directory

on the new system

```
dpkg --set-selections < installed-software
```

this will read the selection and install

Comment: I don't think you read the question.